# What's the equivalent of numpy.spacing(1) in libtorch?

Tags: c++, numpy, torch, libtorch

It seems pytorch does have/expose the `finfo` [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/type_info.html), but I can't find it in `libtorch`. Is it even made available in libtorch yet or not? Using the torch.finfo I could easily do:

```py
esp = torch.finfo(torch.float).eps
```

which I believe is the counterpart/equivalent of `np.spacing(1)` but in libtorch I can't do the same thing as I can not find any trace of `finfo` class. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, we can simply use `std::nextafter` just fine. And also `torch::nextafter` is recently added ([#42580](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/42580)) and uses  this under the hood!

So if you don't use nighlybuilds, and until 1.7 ships, you can simply use `std::nextafter` just fine! Concerning the `THPFinfo`:

> THPFInfo and THPFInfo_eps exist to make this information available in
> python

[Source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/43461#issuecomment-679361214)

Answer (score 1):

There is a TypeInfo.cpp module (pytorch/torch/csrc/TypeInfo.cpp), unfortunately the method you mentioned (torch.finfo(torch.float).eps) seems to be private, as it's marked `static` within a translation unit:

```
static PyObject* THPFInfo_eps(THPFInfo* self, void*) {
  return AT_DISPATCH_FLOATING_AND_COMPLEX_TYPES_AND2(at::kHalf, at::ScalarType::BFloat16,
      self->type, "epsilon", [] {
        return PyFloat_FromDouble(
            std::numeric_limits<
                at::scalar_value_type<scalar_t>::type>::epsilon());
      });
}
```

But, within the corresponding header, there's an extern declaration:

```
extern PyTypeObject THPFInfoType;
```

`THPFInfoType` seems to be an instance which contains a pointer for the following function: `THPFInfo_str`. This function, on the other hand, prints the following:

```
PyObject* THPFInfo_str(THPFInfo* self) {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << "finfo(resolution=" << PyFloat_AsDouble(THPFInfo_resolution(self, nullptr));
  oss << ", min=" << PyFloat_AsDouble(THPFInfo_min(self, nullptr));
  oss << ", max=" << PyFloat_AsDouble(THPFInfo_max(self, nullptr));
  oss << ", eps=" << PyFloat_AsDouble(THPFInfo_eps(self, nullptr));
  oss << ", tiny=" << PyFloat_AsDouble(THPFInfo_tiny(self, nullptr));
  oss << ", dtype=" << PyUnicode_AsUTF8(THPFInfo_dtype(self, nullptr)) << ")";

  return THPUtils_packString(oss.str().c_str());
}
```

Which apparently prints `eps` information. Maybe you could somehow link your target with TypeInfo.cpp and make use of above definitions?

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it. will have a look at this